# c - warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’

Tags: c

I know alot of similar questions were asked before but i couldn't find something that would fix this warning i get:

```
MyIntFunctions.c:19:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Occurs here:

```
void IntPrint (const void *key)
{
    printf("%d", *(int*)key); // line 19
    printf("\t-->\t");
}
```

and a similar warning:

```
MyStringFunctions.c:22:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

void StringPrint (const void *key)
{
    printf("%s",(char*)key); //line 22
    printf("\t-->\t");
}
```

I really want to understand what is wrong so i won't do that again in the future.

Comment: Did you consider including `<stdio.h>`

Comment: Please show us how do you include header file.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You need to include the appropriate header

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

If you're not sure which header a standard function is defined in, the function's [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) will state this.

Answer (score 16):

You need to include a declaration of the `printf()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

the warning or error of kind IMPLICIT DECLARATION is that the compiler is expecting a Function Declaration/Prototype..

It might either be a header file or your own function Declaration..

Answer (score -1):

`warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'`

`warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'scanf'`

the above warnings of compiler says that there is need to include declaration of `printf` and `scanf` i.e. include appropriate header

```
#include <stdio.h>
```