# Warning when using printf

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c - warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069226/c-warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-printf)

Just learning C. I'm getting warnings in a hello world program:

```
main()
{
    printf("Hi\n");
}
```

here's the warning:

```
x.c: In function 'main':
x.c:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
```

How can I eliminate it?

Comment: You forgot `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning.

Comment: Also, `main()` should be at least `int main()` but most preferrably `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: But it SHOULD be an error: use `-Wall -Werror` when compiling. Even the Linux kernel does that to a large degree these days.

Comment: This is, in fact a duplicate of what @birryree linked. It covers exactly the same ground. I'm re-opening this so that the most appropriate close reason is applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing the #include that declares the libraries.

add :

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

  ...etc
```

you need to declare functions before they can be used.

Answer (score 8):

You haven't included header file `stdio.h` you can include this by `#include<stdio.h>`

A header file contains forward declarations of functions and variables. Every external function will be mentioned in a header file, including libraries that are pre-compiled into object code, and source files required to build the C program

what you need to so is  thanks to the `#include` line, which tells it where the definition of printf can be found.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("Hi\n");
}
```

---

check [**The  Header File**](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/stdio.html)

and printf=> [`void printf (const char *format, ...);`](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/stdio.html#printf)

---

and now explanation of above program

in line first

`#`=>  it is Processors  the `preprocessor` is a translation phase that is applied to your source code before the compiler proper gets its hands on it

recomended reading [**C - Pre-Processors**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_preprocessors.htm)

`main()` function  => the main function is where a program starts execution. It is responsible for the high-level organization of the program's functionality, and typically has access to the command arguments given to the program when it was executed.

`printf()`  is nearly full implementation of standard ANSI C `printf` function, which sends the formatted output to the screen in terminal (TTY) mode. this is belongs to `stdio.h` header file

good read [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#C_and_C.2B.2B) and  [Where are C/C++ main function's parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196860/1723893)

Answer (score 6):

You are not including the library, add this before you start your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

because you are using `printf()` and it's an output function, belongs to `stdio.h` library...

Answer (score 1):

Include the following header file to access the definition of `printf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

incompatible implicit declaration...
     This sentence tells something is to be there before printf. That something is #include "Every inbuilt function in C should refer Predefined procedures present in lib's"

Answer (score 0):

Include header file in your program..

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

Implicit declaration warning occurs when the compiler is expecting a `function declaration` or  `function prototype`
and printf() function prototype is declared in `#include<stdio.h>`