# warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm using the following C code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    int file=0;
    if((file=open("testfile.txt",O_RDONLY)) < -1)
            return 1;
    char buffer[19];
    if(read(file,buffer,19) != 19)  return 1;
    printf("%s\n",buffer);

    if(lseek(file,10,SEEK_SET) < 0) return 1;

    if(read(file,buffer,19) != 19)  return 1;
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling it produces a warning:

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in 
function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
```

What does it mean and how do I appease the C compiler to not raise the warning?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [c - warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069226/c-warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-printf)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You need to add `#include <stdio.h>` to the top of your file.

Comment: @rkioji because the compiler makes guess about the definition of a function and it makes good guess about the function present in stdio.h